# How to download in multi-thread using Jenkins Artifactory plugin or other options?

Tags: multithreading, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, artifactory, jfrog-cli

In my company we're having a bad time trying to download with the [Artifactoy plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin) in Jenkins because we have a lot of tiny files in our repository and apparently the plugin works in a single thread, so it takes a REALLY long time.

We tested the [JFrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/JFrog+CLI) where we can set the number of threads for the download and that actually works great. Still, we really need to use the original plugin.

Is there any workaround for this?

Maybe it has something to do with the Artifactory server configuration?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can download artifacts in multi-thread using [Jrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory) from your pipeline code.

You can have threads in your Groovy code launching the download command of [Jrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory).

For example:

```
$ jfrog rt dl my-local-repo/your-folder/*
```

Download all artifacts of your folder in the repo to the current directory(in your Jenkins local directory).

Comment: As I mentioned, we tested it and it worked really fast as expected but the JFrog CLI is not optimized for Jenkins but is rather a generic solution. One of the pitfalls we came across with it is that it doesn't really save all the Jenkins-specific build information metadata, a thing we require for later promoting the builds. This for example is being done great with the original Jenkins Artifactory plugin